# Exporting layer selection to a file GDB

Tags: arcgis-10.0, esri-geodatabase

I have over sixty layers in a map. These are all grouped by categories. I am trying to figure out the best way to export all the layers for a given selection to a file geodatabase and also maintain the group layers.

I looked into the GP tools but didnt find a tool that supports seelction set.

Looking for some ideas.

Thanks
Jay

Comment: So in essence do you want featuredatasets in your FGDB that represent the group layers in your MXD? And the layers from each group layer would then go into the corresponding featuredataset via the export?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: As far as the export process goes, all GP tools support a selection set.  Therefore if you have 1 of 10 features selected, only the 1 feature will be exported.